# Android change event definition from other class

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have a main class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    downloadTask downloadTask;
    ....
    void updateProgress(int... progress) {

    }
}
```

and an AsyncTask

```
public class downloadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, double[], Void> {
    ....
    protected void onProgressUpdate(int... progress) {
    }    
}
```

Is there a way that I can set the `onProgressUpdate` & override it so that it uses `updateProgress` instead, from the `MainActivity`?

I'm aware I can create a new class that extends `downloadTask` and use `@Override` there. I'm just wondering if there's another way. For instance in javascript I could do something like

```
downloadTask.onProgressUpdate = updateProgress
```

Is something like this possible in java?

Comment: http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html. check this if it helpes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
AsyncTask<Void, double[], Void> task = new AsyncTask<Void, double[], Void>(activity);
{
     private WeakReference<Activity> activityReference;

     public AsyncTask(Activity activity)
     {
          this.activityReference = new WeakReference<Activity>(activity);
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(int... progress) 
     {
         Activity activity = activityReference.get();
         if(activity != null)
         {
             activity.updateProgres(...);
         }
     }    
}
```

Note that I use WeakReference inside the AsyncTask, this is very important to prevent memory leaks.